Having problems with group of units generators
Sorry if the question is quite basic, I started learning Mathematica today to help me with group computations.
I'm trying to get the generators of the group of units modulo p, with p a prime. However, I'm getting results that are not quite right.
My code is:
For[i=3,i<1000,i+=2,
If[PrimeQ[i],Print[i];
Print[FiniteGroupData[{"CyclicGroupUnits",i},"Generators"]]  
]
]

I'm sorry if the indentation isn't the best one, I'm using one I can understand.
The first lines of output of my code are:
3
{2}
5
{2}
7
{2,3}
9
{2,3}
11
{2,3}
13
{2,4}
I don't understand why I got {2,3} as a generator for 7. The group is generated by {3} alone. One quick way to solve this could be removing the first element of every set (2), but then I would lose the groups that are actually generated by {2} (I've tried it). I don't know why the output gives me a set with 2 in every line, when that number doesn't make sense.
I have tried to read documentation and searched for similar question, but found nothing. I hope I didn't make a really stupid mistake. Any help is greatly appreciated :)
edit: I'm clarifying why my question isn't a duplicate, for those who are trying to close it. As correctly pointed out by @azerbajdzan I'm trying to find the generators of the group of units, not their elements or the primitive roots. Finding those sets wouldn't help in any way. Also, if I tried to find the generators of those sets I would get the same output (so the mistake would still remain). Thank you anyway for trying to help, but your recommendations and links are not helpful.
Also, thanks for all the other comments and the people who are genuinely trying to help me. Yes, I made some big mistakes (the "if" instead of "If", that makes me print all odd numbers), thanks for pointing them out and correcting me. Sorry for them, I tried my best but it's my first time (in the past I used some c++, java and python, so I'm not used to the different syntax)

Does this work (other than the weirdly Missing data for 19)? Table[{Prime[k],    FiniteGroupData[{"CyclicGroupUnits", k}, "Generators"]}, {k, 2, 10}]. Also: if I run your code, I get {2} as the generator of 7, so it seems as if our output doesn't agree.

Sorry: I see why it went weird for 19: It should be Table[{Prime[k],    FiniteGroupData[{"CyclicGroupUnits", Prime[k]}, "Generators"]}, {k,    2, 40}]. Of course, all of the generator lists are just {2}.

This question is similar to: Finding the group of residue classes modulo n under multiplication. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Take a look at, for example, FiniteGroupData[{"CyclicGroupUnits", 14}, "Elements"]. You will see that they are just named sequentially from 1 to the order of the group (6), as mentioned in the documentation. Please look at the question I linked to see how you can get the actual elements {1, 3, 5, 9, 11, 13} :)

@Domen Where that link address the problem of finding the generators of group?

@Mati, you may also want to look at PrimitiveRootList.

Would be great if the two "close voters as a duplicate" could show us the links of which OP question is duplicate of. The OP question is not a duplicate of Domen's link.

@Mati Can the question be simplified to why FiniteGroupData[{"CyclicGroupUnits", 7}, "Generators"] gives {2,3}? I would ask that if so you edit your question. The errors in your code are sort of obfuscating the question (e.g. if instead of If, extraneous Prints, the fact that you're producing results for odd integers instead of primes, and the fact that anyone actually running your code will get ~500 outputs to look at)

@Domen sorry, I don't think your link is helping me. As pointed out by azerbajdzan I'm trying to find the generators. Thank you anyway for your help and time

@everyone thank you for all the help. Yes I saw I made some big mistakes (printing all odd numbers and other things), thanks for pointing out. I'll try all your recommendations tomorrow morning :)

@lericr yes, thank you. It could be written like that. I'm looking for a more general answer, but I guess if anyone finds something that works for 7, it will also work in the general case. Thanks for the time and the help :)

@Mati Can you explain why you think 3 is the only generator of group for p=7? Why not also 5?

@Mati I think that it is a bug. Or they in Wolfram mean something completely different by "CyclicGroupUnits" or by "Generators" than a standard definition.

I agree with @azerbajdzan. This is a bug. Grid[FiniteGroupData[{"CyclicGroupUnits", 7}, "MultiplicationTable"]] gives an incorrect multiplication table which is the same as that of {"CyclicGroup", 6} . The correct result is Grid[Table[Mod[i*j, 7], {i, 1, 6}, {j, 1, 6}]].

@azerbajdzan Also 5 could be a generator. I'm currently trying to find the smallest one so I focused the question on 3, but yes, 5 is also a generator indeed

@A.Kato oh, so how could I possibly fix that to make my program work as intended? Do you have any suggestion?

I couldn't fix your program. Instead I tried coding from scratch and put it as an answer below.

@A.Kato thank you very much!

For prime $p$, $(Z_{p})^{\times} \simeq Z/(p-1)Z$ as a group. So your problem is equivalent to the one in How to find a generator of a cyclic group?. This is tractable if all the factors of $p{-}1$ are known and they are not too large. I will use the algorithm 4.80 from Handbook of applied cryptography cited in the discussion above.
The Mathematica code goes something like this:
Clear["Global`*"];
cyclicGroupUnitsGenerators[2] := {}; (* Exceptional case. The group is trivial *)
cyclicGroupUnitsGenerators[p_Integer?PrimeQ] := 
  Module[{generatorQ, n, powers},
   n = p - 1;
   powers = (n/#[[1]]) & /@ FactorInteger[n];
   generatorQ[x_] := AllTrue[powers, PowerMod[x, #, p] != 1 &];
   Select[Range[2, n], generatorQ]
   ];

For primes less than 100:
list = Table[{p, cyclicGroupUnitsGenerators[p]}, 
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　{p, Select[Range[3,100], PrimeQ]}];
Grid[Prepend[list,
  {"p", "generators of (\[DoubleStruckCapitalZ]/p\
\[DoubleStruckCapitalZ]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\()\), \(\[Times]\)]\)" \
}], Frame -> All]


Remark For general $n$, the group $(Z/nZ)^{\times}$ is not necessarily a cyclic group, but an abelian group. As explained in Theorem 2.10 of Cyclic groups and elementary number theory II,
it is a cyclic group if and only if $n$ is either (1) an odd prime power, (2) twice an odd prime power, or (3) $2$ or $4$.
As explained in the second line of the MMA Document, this is the only cases when PrimitiveRootList[n] returns non-empty answer.

Thank you very much! I'll need to do other stuff with generators, is it a problem if I ask you to briefly explain how this code works? (what the commands are doing, etc.)? If you have other stuff to do no problem, but it would be of great help :)

Another thing, I'll need to study the generators also on quite big numbers. You said "This is tractable if all the factors of −1 are known and they are not too large.": what do you think could be the maximum number that makes the code work? 10^8? 10^100? How far can I take it (approximately)?

No need to reinvent the wheel: As I've suggested, just use the built-in PrimitiveRootList.

@Domen I'm not looking for that. I'm not searching for the primitive roots, but the generators of the group. Knowing the primitive roots wouldn't help in any way. How could I get the generators from them?? That set is a completely different one

@Mati, please open the link I've provided and read the first line: A primitive root is a generator for the multiplicative group of integers modulo n relatively prime to n. Grid@Table[{Prime[i], PrimitiveRootList[Prime[i]]}, {i, 2, 25}] gives the exact same result as the A. Kato's table.

@Mati For the groups you’re looking at, primitive roots are generators.

@Domen yes, but as I explained then I need to generalize to non prime numbers, so primitive roots won't work

@Domen, @lericr You are right. I'm reinventing the wheel (^_^). Since OP is a new user of MMA, so I thought it would be kind to show a sample code. Moreover as @Mati claims,  PrimitiveRootList[120] does not answer the generator of $(Z/120Z)^{\times}$.

@Mati I don't have enough time right now. I will add some explanation later. Do you also want the generators of $(Z/nZ)^\times$ for composite $n$?

@A.Kato don't worry, I don't want to bother you. It could be useful to have the generators of (/p)× and of (/p^2 )×, but if you can't work on it right now it is not a problem. Thank you for what you have already done :)

@Mati I added some remark to my answer. The paper cited there may be useful to your problem.

@Mati As for the computational complexity, I'm not an expert and have no useful answer. Please consult literature on cryptography.

@A.Kato Thank you, I will!

Update:
I think I have some support for my hypothesis (see Previous musings). Consider the documentation for GroupGenerators, http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupGenerators.html, and the tech note for permutation groups, http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PermutationGroups.html.
Notice that the tech note starts right off the bat with this:

all finite groups can be represented as permutation groups

and that suggests to me that Mathematica may have chosen to base all of their finite group data on permutations. If we ask for the actual group, we get
FiniteGroupData[{"CyclicGroupUnits", 7}, "PermutationGroupRepresentation"]
(* {Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{4, 5}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}}], 
    Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}}], Cycles[{{1, 3, 2}}], Cycles[{{1, 3, 2}, {4, 5}}]} *)

and we can see that the generators are
GroupGenerators[FiniteGroupData[{"CyclicGroupUnits", 7}, "PermutationGroupRepresentation"]]
(* {Cycles[{{4, 5}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}}]} *)

The point being that "generators" doesn't mean generating elements, but generating permutations (obviously the generating permutations are also elements, but their generator-ness is based on combining them as permutations and not on their order individually). Let's take a different example and compare:
FiniteGroupData[{"CyclicGroupUnits", 13}, "PermutationGroupRepresentation"]
(* PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{5, 6, 7}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4}}]}] *)

GroupElements[FiniteGroupData[{"CyclicGroupUnits", 13}, "PermutationGroupRepresentation"]]
(* {Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{5, 6, 7}}], Cycles[{{5, 7, 6}}], 
    Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7}}], 
    Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 7, 6}}], Cycles[{{1, 3}, {2, 4}}],  
    Cycles[{{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5, 6, 7}}], Cycles[{{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5, 7, 6}}], 
    Cycles[{{1, 4, 3, 2}}], Cycles[{{1, 4, 3, 2}, {5, 6, 7}}], 
    Cycles[{{1, 4, 3, 2}, {5, 7, 6}}]} *)

Now, is it just coincidence that we get the following?
FiniteGroupData[{"CyclicGroupUnits", 13}, "Generators"]
(* {2, 4} *)

Let's take yet another example:
FiniteGroupData[{"CyclicGroupUnits", 31}, "Generators"]
(* {2, 3, 7} *)

FiniteGroupData[{"CyclicGroupUnits", 31}, "PermutationGroupRepresentation"]
(* PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{9, 10}}], Cycles[{{6, 7, 8}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}]}] *)

GroupElements[FiniteGroupData[{"CyclicGroupUnits", 31}, "PermutationGroupRepresentation"]][[{2, 3, 7}]]
(* {Cycles[{{9, 10}}], Cycles[{{6, 7, 8}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}]} *)

So, my concrete hypotheses are that (1) Mathematica implements all FiniteGroupData stuff as permutation groups, and (2) the output from FiniteGroupData[..., "Generators"] is a list of indices into the group element list in canonical form per PermutationGroup. I would agree that (2) is not well documented, initially quite surprising, and seemingly rather useless.
Previous musings:
Just an extended comment/hypothesis, not a well-informed answer...
I suspect this is a matter of Mathematica choosing a canonical representation. I'd love to hear from the mathematicians in the group (omg, pun not intended).
Consider the following:
PermutationOrder /@ FiniteGroupData[{"CyclicGroupUnits", 7}, "PermutationRepresentation"]
(* {1, 2, 3, 6, 3, 6} *)

So, we do indeed have two generators. But clearly we can't assume that the indices are mapped to the original integer-mod-7 equivalence classes. The original element 6 obviously doesn't have order 6. The permutation representation lists the elements like this:
FiniteGroupData[{"CyclicGroupUnits", 7}, "PermutationRepresentation"]
(* {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 4}, {2, 3, 1, 4, 5}, 
    {2, 3, 1, 5, 4}, {3, 1, 2, 4, 5}, {3, 1, 2, 5, 4}} *)

If I'm thinking about it correctly, the original mod-7 equivalence classes put into this same order would be {1, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5} (or maybe that with some swaps applied). Does that have any significance? IDK.
Anyway, the permutation representations clearly do not map to the original equivalence classes in the same order, so I think it's a least plausible that none of the other canonical representations Mathematica might be using can be assumed to correspond to that order. I.e. I think it might be possible that for the generators {2,3} 2 does not mean 2Z and 3 does not mean 3Z.
Let me re-emphasize that I'm just trying to understand what I'm reading in the documentation and also making what I think are plausible assumptions. I have very low confidence that I actually understand what's going on here.

I really don't know, but thank you for your time. I'm currently trying to study the generators to try to understand a strange exception of a theorem (I wanna know if there are more and, eventually, if they are finite or infinite), but the way Mathematica gives the generators is quite confusing. I assume that it is made in the most efficient way (i.e. picking the first element and making its powers until it repeats, then going to the next element etc.), instead of looking for the first element which its powers are all the other elements. I think he doesn't assume my set is a cyclic group

@Mati Please see my update to my "answer". The real question now is can you use the representations based on permutation groups to do what you want to do?

Honestly I don't know if I can.. But thank you for the answer. Yes, you're totally right. I don't know why Mathematica does this instead of using the definitions. It's strange, and yes it's also really useless indeed
